# Golang parsing into struct

Tags: json, api, go, nested

I cannot parse this json into my structure. Can anyone please help with this

```
{"error":false,"response":{"results":[{"id":68876,"name":"cee lo green - big girls"},{"id":68954,"name":"charles, ray - the girl friend"},{"id":69603,"name":"charlie puth - la girls"},{"id":68001,"name":"city girls - careless"},{"id":68000,"name":"city girls - millionaire dick"},{"id":68002,"name":"city girls - period (we live)"},{"id":68004,"name":"city girls - rap shit"},{"id":68003,"name":"city girls - runnin"},{"id":68019,"name":"clairo - pretty girl"},{"id":68223,"name":"cohn, marc - girl of mysterious sorrow"},{"id":68343,"name":"contours, the - searching for a girl"}
```

Below is my struct
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"
"log"
"net/http")

type test struct{
SngID       string `json:"id"`
SngNm       string `json:"name"`
}
type Inner struct{

```
Result[10] test `json:"results"`
```

}

type Outer struct{
Eror bool `json:"error"`
Response [] Inner `json:"results"`

}

Comment: I tried to mimic the my data structure to the structure of json. But the json data is not parsing into my struct. Below is my Code

Comment: I added my code to the my question. Can you please suggest something what mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is malformed (check the error returned by json.Unmarshal).

Anyway, this struct should work for you.

```golang
    type Response struct {
        Error    bool `json:"error"`
        Response struct {
            Results []struct {
                ID   int    `json:"id"`
                Name string `json:"name"`
            } `json:"results"`
        } `json:"response"`
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the Response. I tried the struct you gave. Its still not parsing values for id and name   My output looks like this: Just parsing bool value for error   [{Error:false Response:{Results:[{ID:0 Name:} {ID:0 Name:} {ID:0 Name:} {ID:0 Name:} {ID:0 Name:}]}}]
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I tested it with the json you gave and it works: https://play.golang.org/p/-ccZbeEDtH-. Could you provide a playground reproduction of the error?

Comment: Yeah, I got the json from there too and tested it. Works fine.

Comment: Can I parse this json using a map in my struct for id and name. I tried using map to but didn't work.